# When I try to change mode in VI it prompts ^[ char

Tags: linux, vi, freebsd

I am using FreeBsd 9 and I need to use Vi. 
My problem related with the changing mode (command to insert or insert to command) in VI. 
I know that I need to use ESC key to change mode. 
But in Insert mode (while typing some codes) when I press ESC key it prompts ' ^[ ' char.
It doesn't let me switch command mode insert to command.

Do you know any fix or settings for this ?

Comment: Perhaps you have some mappings interfering? Do you see any with ":map <Esc>" and ":map! <Esc>"?

Answer (score 0):

I may not understand what you are asking, but, have you tried pressing colon instead of escape?

Comment: Yes i tried every combination. I just improve my question. Thanks you.